# ClickOnce unable to install LocalDB 2012 on Windows Vista SP2

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, windows-vista, localdb

I have developed a winforms application based on Microsoft .NET 4.5 framework. The app is deployed using the ClickOnce publishing method. I have also invested a lot of time to set up signing of both my assembly and ClickOnce's setup exe. The signing works. One of my application's prerequisites is LocalDB (2012), which ClickOnce installs, if it is not present on the users machine.

The .NET framework's specification states, that the supported OS's are:

- Windows Vista SP2
- Windows 7 SP1
- Windows 8
- Windows 8.1

I tried installing my app on all of these and it works as expected, except for Windows Vista SP2.

While downloading and installing other prerequisites, it fails to install one of them. The error message says:

> Setup has detected that the publisher of file '...\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD56A2.tmp\SqlLocalDB2012\x86\sqlcmdlnutils.msi' cannot be verified. Click OK to retry the download, or Cancel to exit setup.

[image]

Clicking OK only closes the window and issues the same error again.

I tried to install my app on a different computer with Vista SP2 - same issue. Does anybody know, why this error occurs and how to resolve it? Tried searching the web for similar issues, but haven't found anything.

**UPDATE #1:** As Krzysztof Kozielczyk suggested, I tried installing the problematic MSI packages manually. Downloading and installing`sqlncli.msi` and `SqlCmdLnUtils.msi` from Microsoft succesfully resolves the first two errors.

However, ClickOnce shortly issues the same type of warning for `SqlLocalDB.msi`. As I did with the other two prerequisites, I downloaded the MSI from Microsoft and installed LocalDB manually, but this time ClickOnce does not recognize it and still tries to install it, which fails.

**UPDATE #2:** Further examination showed, that the problem lies in the expired digital signatures of the MSI-s that clickonce tries to download.

[image]

I also reported this bug to the [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1082242/clickonce-unable-to-install-localdb-2012-on-windows-vista-sp2).

The problematic MSI-s shoud be signed again. Can I expect from Microsoft to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried manually installing the MSI mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Will try to do that shortly and update my question.

Comment: Dear @AlexB. I saw your post on Microsoft Connect as well, but they are not offering any solution. Did you find any solution yourself? If so, it would be really helpful if you can share the same.

Thx,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with the SqlCmdLnUtils.msi package that ClickOnce installer pulls from the Microsoft Downloads site. Either the package is broken (bad upload, corrupt binaries on CDN, you name it), or the FWLink is broken.

In the generated ClickOnce package you should be able to find the link that's used for downloading the binary. It will look something like `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkld=012345`. Just paste it to your browser and see what happens. If the link is broken, an error page will be displayed. If the link works it will download the **exact** package ClickOnce is trying to use, and hopefully you will be able to use it to determine what's wrong with it.

In both cases you'll likely need to inform Microsoft of the problem, maybe file a [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) item.